# Azure Media SDK incompatibility issue when running set up scripts in PowerShell

Tags: azure

I was following this tutorial here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MediaServices/thread/a9d3d1b4-09eb-4a28-ad1d-a1f4cf3123cb  on how to set up Azure Media Services.

But when running scripts in PowerShell, specifically, when I run the following command: .\GetMediaServicesEnv.ps1 (this command is supposed to prompt me to download the publishsettings file)

I get an error message:
The installed Azure SDK version is not supported. Make sure you version is between v1.6 and v1.6 inclusive
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure Media Services\Services\v1.0\GetMediaServicesEnv.ps1:5 char:25
+ Get-AzurePublishSettings <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception

This is strange since the newest and the only available version is 1.7, which I already downloaded. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

By the way, I am using Win7 - 64 bit version.

Answer (score 2):

You are right 1.7 is the latest, but you are not right it is the only one available. Windows Azure Media Services was CTP'ed before SDK 1.7 was available, so it wonly works with 1.6 (yet). Tghe good news for you is that 1.6 and 1.7 can work side-by-side, and you can have 1.6 projects, as well 1.7 projects and they will work fine.

So to work with Azure Media Services SDK, you need Windows Azure SDK 1.6 and Windows Azure Libraries for .NET 1.6. You can install them via the Web Platform Installer. Just search for "Azure" then find them in the results. Something like:

[image]

It might be a tricky though. I never tried installing 1.6 after having 1.7. I had 1.6 installed, and then added 1.7 and everything works. If you have any issues installing 1.6, try first removing 1.7, then install 1.6, then add 1.7 and you will have side-by-side 1.6 and 1.7 Windows Azure SDKs.

Comment: Great!Thanks a lot for the answer. I spent a whole day trying to figure it out and just got off the phone with tech support. 
They too told me the same thing. I just wasn't looking for the right place to look for SDK 1.6. How can I file a bug to Azure Media team by the way?

Comment: Check out these forum threads for similar issues to yours. If none found, start a new thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MediaServices/threads